# disabled plugin and now wordpress won't load

Tags: plugins

My WP site was infected with malware, probably from the plug-in WPBakery.
Initially I just took the bad code from index.php and the site worked.
Then, I disabled WPBakery, and now my site won't load and I can't get into the editor.
It just says:

*There has been a critical error on this website.*

I tried to re-enable it using wp-cli but it says

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function 
vc_add_param() in /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/boldial-gm-child/functions.php:139
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-settings.php(591): include()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1336): require('/home/mysite...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1254): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#7 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/boldial-gm-child/functions.php on line 139
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function vc_add_param() 
in /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/boldial-gm-child/functions.php:139
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-settings.php(591): include()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1336): require('/home/mysite...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1254): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#7 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /home/mysite/web/mysite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/boldial-gm-child/functions.php on line 139
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your plugins folder temporarily to disable all plugins. .

If necessary, also rename your active theme's folder, then upload WP core.

Then reinstall WP manually (unzip to local, then upload) - saving your wp-config.php file first

That should get you access to admin. Then follow the steps here to clean up your site:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/415705/29416

Then add fresh copies/installs of your theme and needed plugins (don't copy the old ones).

Comment: "If necessary, also rename your active theme's folder" AH that's what I was missing, thanks